# How do you run a .command file with cocoa programming language?

Tags: cocoa, command

I'm brand new to Cocoa programming and was wondering how to run a .command file through my program. I've seen use of NSTask but being new I don't quite understand all of the lines and can't seem to get it to work. I don't need to monitor the terminal results or retrieve the data that terminal puts out, I just need to run it.

Comment: “…being new I don't quite understand all of the lines…” That's what the documentation is for: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/ The documentation explains what each method does, and there's a link to the relevant guide document near the top and on the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way is:

```
system("/path/to/my/script.command");
```

This is not Cocoa, this is Posix.